# UISegmentedControl reload certain page

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm using a third party library for my UISegmentedControl. The pages are initialised as following:

```
func carbonTabSwipeNavigation(carbonTabSwipeNavigation: CarbonTabSwipeNavigation, viewControllerAtIndex index: UInt) -> UIViewController {
    switch index {
    case 0:
        return self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FolderOverviewController") as! FolderOverviewController
    case 1:
        return self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TopFoldersTab") as! TopFoldersTab
    case 2:
        return self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CategoriesFolderTab") as! CategoriesFolderTab
    default:
        return self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CategoriesFolderTab") as! CategoriesFolderTab
    }

}
```

When I press the third segment, the user can go further down to see more details (via subviews on the same page). I would like the page to reload, every time I select the third segment again. (go back to the original CategoriesFolderTab page) . Currently I'm doing this with a `ViewDidLoad()`, but this is slowing down the app when you do it multiple times.

Is there a more correct way to do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think that  calling `viewDidLoad()` is not the right approach for achieving this, instead, implement a new function that should contains code responsible for loading data in the UI components, for example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    reloadUI()
}

func reloadUI() {
    // filling UI components with desired data, such as:
    // myLabel.text = "Hello World"
}
```

And somewhere in your code (where you want to reload), instead of calling `viewDidLoad()`, you should call `reloadUI()` method.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Let folderOverVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FolderOverviewController") as! FolderOverviewController
Let topFoldersTab = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TopFoldersTab") as! TopFoldersTab
Let categoriesFolderTab = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CategoriesFolderTab") as! CategoriesFolderTab



func carbonTabSwipeNavigation(carbonTabSwipeNavigation: CarbonTabSwipeNavigation, viewControllerAtIndex index: UInt) -> UIViewController {
switch index {
case 0:
    return folderOverVC
case 1:
    return topFoldersTab
case 2:
    return categoriesFolderTab
default:
    return categoriesFolderTab
}

}
```

this initializes the view controllers once, so their respective viewDidLoad methods get called once initialized, not every time you tap a tab item